# How to automate a button's action with tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I would like to achieve, when I click on the "Autopaging" button each page from the PDF gets displayed for 1s. Now when I click it, its loops through the list of pages, jumps to the last page, and doesn't display any other page.

To the auto_read function I placed print(pagenumber) to see when its looping through the pages.

```
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
from pdf2image import convert_from_path
import time

class SuReader:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.next_but = Button(root, text='>>', command=lambda: self.next_page())
        self.prev_but = Button(root, text='<<', command=self.prev_page)
        self.automate_but = Button(root, text='Autopaging', command=self.auto_read)
        self.next_but.grid(row=1, column=2)
        self.prev_but.grid(row=1, column=0)
        self.automate_but.grid(row=1, column=1)
        self.display_pages()


    def get_pages(self):
        self.pages = convert_from_path('book.pdf', size=(700, 600))
        self.photos = []
        for i in range(len(self.pages)):
            self.photos.append(ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.pages[i]))


    def display_pages(self):
        self.get_pages()
        self.page_number = 0
        self.content = Label(self.root, image=self.photos[self.page_number])
        self.content.grid(column=0,row=0,sticky='NSEW', columnspan=3)
        print(len(self.photos))


    def next_page(self):
        # self.page_number += 1
        self.content.destroy()
        self.content = Label(self.root, image=self.photos[self.page_number])
        self.content.grid(column=0,row=0,sticky='NSEW', columnspan=3)
        self.page_number += 1



    def prev_page(self):
        self.page_number -= 1
        print(self.page_number)
        self.content.destroy()
        self.content = Label(self.root, image=self.photos[self.page_number])
        self.content.grid(column=0,row=0,sticky='NSEW', columnspan=3)


    def auto_read(self):
        for i in range(len(self.photos)):
            time.sleep(1)
            print(self.page_number)
            self.next_page()


root = Tk()
root.title('Book Reader')
program = SuReader(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Here I just pass it to the next_page function, but even if I define properly it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`time.sleep` is blocking `mainloop` and I believe you are also having a garbage collection problem. I rewrote your code and solved your problems. I solved other problems you were about to have, as well. The changes are commented in the script.

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
from pdf2image import convert_from_path

class App(tk.Tk):
    WIDTH  = 700
    HEIGHT = 640
    TITLE  = 'Book Reader'
    
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, **kwargs)
        
        #get_pages and display_pages are useless just do it all in the constructor
        self.pages  = convert_from_path('book.pdf', size=(700, 600))
        self.photos = {}
        for i in range(len(self.pages)):
            #the image might get garbage collected if you don't do it this way
            self.photos[f'photo_{i}'] = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.pages[i])
            
        self.auto     = tk.IntVar()
        self.was_auto = False
        
        self.page_number = 0
        self.content     = tk.Label(self, image=self.photos[f'photo_{self.page_number}'])
        self.content.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky='nsew', columnspan=3)
        
        tk.Button(self, text='<<', command=self.prev_page).grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='w')
        tk.Checkbutton(self, text='auto-paging', variable=self.auto, command=self.auto_page).grid(row=1, column=1)
        tk.Button(self, text='>>', command=self.next_page).grid(row=1, column=2, sticky='e')
        
        self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(2, weight=1)
        
    def next_page(self):
        #stop a lingering `after` call from affecting anything if we unchecked auto-paging
        if self.auto.get() == 0 and self.was_auto:
            self.was_auto = False
            return
            
        self.page_number += 1
        #never be out of range
        self.page_number = self.page_number % len(self.pages)
        #you don't have to remake the Label every time, just reassign it's image property
        self.content['image'] = self.photos[f'photo_{self.page_number}']
        
        #time.sleep(1) replacement ~ non-blocking 
        if self.auto.get() == 1:
            self.after(1000, self.next_page)

    def prev_page(self):
        self.page_number -= 1
        #never be out of range
        if self.page_number < 0:
            self.page_number += len(self.pages)
        self.content['image'] = self.photos[f'photo_{self.page_number}']
        
    def auto_page(self):
        if self.auto.get() == 1:
           #allows us to catch a lingering `after` call if auto-paging is unchecked
           self.was_auto = True
           self.next_page()
            

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = App()
    app.title(App.TITLE)
    app.geometry(f'{App.WIDTH}x{App.HEIGHT}')
    app.resizable(width=False, height=False)
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: @BryanOakley ~ the first code works fine. It's the second code that was untested. It was untested because I don't have `pdf2image`. However, I don't see any reason the code should not work. I just replaced my `Message` with his `Label`. Stop down-voting me without even testing my code. The first script works perfect. The second script IS the first script with a widget replacement.

Comment: I apologize. I thought the answer was confusing for someone who is still learning how to program. If you feel strongly that this is a good answer, you'll need to edit the answer slightly in order for me to remove my downvote.

Comment: Both code is working for me. The auto-paging just like how i wanted. Thanks for the help! You deserve an up vote! As soon as I have my reputation to give it, i will.

Comment: @MarkGemesi - When an answer solves your problem you are supposed to accept it. You do this by clicking the gray check-mark to the left side of an answer. If you have the reputation you can also upvote the answer, but accepting an answer marks it as correct. You can only accept 1 answer per question. Accepting an answer does not require any reputation. I'm glad my code works for you and I am happy to help.

Comment: @BryanOakley I think he explained it pretty well in the code, he commented every change he made and explained what he did. I am learning python, and just started not too long ago, but i understood his answer. I get your point, but since he commented every step on the code, I think de deserves the up!

Comment: @MichaelGuidry Thanks for the help, I accepted the answer. It not just helped me, but teached me too.

Comment: HAH! You are my new best friend @MarkGemesi. You need some more codes? :D

Comment: To be fair, if it wasn't for @BryanOakley I wouldn't be as good as I am at programming with `tkinter`. I definitely read lots and lots of docs, but I also read lots and lots of his answers. I've only been programming in `python` for 5 months and `tkinter` for about 3 months. Yet, I have amassed almost all of my reputation in one quarter answering mostly `tkinter` questions. BryanOakley definitely deserves some credit for my ability to do that.

Comment: @MichaelGuidry wow, yeah sure. What a beginning of a new friendship. Thank you Stack Overflow. Not only professional but emotional help too. Big up for the community! :D